# css technique for a horizontal line in checkout steps

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a checkout progress meter as in the below fiddle [Fiddle Link Here](http://jsfiddle.net/b32yL29e/1/)

The problem here i am facing that horizontal lines are not in place. Kindly help. I want this as to be displayed as below

[image]

To show timeline code is as below

```
.checkout-broken .timeline {
height: 0;
width: 50%;
position: relative;
top: 31%;
z-index: -1;
border: 1px solid #005387
}
```

Comment: Main problem is padding. If you add 60px padding, the width 50% will be calculated of the inner size, not the one with the padding, so the width will be smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `position` to `absolute`:

```
.checkout-broken .timeline {
    height: 0;
    width: 50%;
  - position: relative;
  + position: absolute;
    top: 31%;
    z-index: -1;
    border: 1px solid #005387
}
```

For removing the gaps between the `.step` elements you can use `float: left;` instead of the `display: inline-block`.

http://jsfiddle.net/62de75kt/

Comment: i do not want to use z-index to hide the line.. is there any other way? new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b32yL29e/5/

Comment: what this calc func do basically

Comment: The function is used for _calculating_ values, Please note that the function is not widely-supported. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you don't want to use z-index to hide it (since I think it's the easiest way) but you can change the alignment to achieve your result. See the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/tga7dbbu/

Here's the part of CSS which has been changed :

```
.checkout-broken .timeline-r {
    right: -20px;
}
.checkout-broken .timeline-l {
    left: -20px;
}
.checkout-broken .step {
    padding: 0 25px;
    margin:0 10px;
}
```

Of course you can tweak it further but the principle is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use :after content

```
Demo:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b32yL29e/7/